# IIS - running PHP does not recognize paths to file

Tags: php, iis

I just installed PHP for IIS7. I've set up a virtual directory to my project so that I can browse to `http://localhost/myproj/index.php`  When I browse to index.php, I get 404 errors for the javascript files that I want to include.

In index.php I'm including them like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/_inc/jquery.js"></script>
```

instead of looking for javascript file under my virtual directory, it tried to search it under root. `http://localhost/_inc/jquery.js`

Is there a way to make it look for includes under my virtual directory?

Comment: vitual directory is the IIS concept.  I'm running PHP on IIS O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of looking for javascript file under my virtual directory, it tried to search it under root.

Because you're telling it to do so. When you define a path with leading slash `/`, then it is *always* treated as absolute. The browser doesn't care about something like "virtual directories".

```
/myproj/_inc/jquery.js
```

Comment: right. putting the '.' in front of the '/' fixes the problem.